# Validating multiple form fields with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have already searched the site and while I found similar issues, I couldn't get the answer I needed, so I am asking now. I need to validate a contact form, the PHP validation is very simple but works on a base level, I want to supplement this with browser validation through JS but it is not working, the JS validation does not trigger or is not correctly coded.

I'm working on this page: http://camp-tags.com/?main_page=contact

Thanks in advance for looking for me.

The function is supposed to loop through and make sure that the 4 elements are not empty, and that both variables for phonenumber and email are formatted correctly. If any flag as false, the error is supposed to be pushed to an array and then all errors output in a single alert.

Below is the code. (updated using the tips given here. No validation at all now.)

*update: I found one glaring error I can not believe I missed. I didn't have a closing tag on the , now that is done, the form will not send unless you input the phone correct but is not validating the rest and no Alert is being issued to advise what is wrong?
JS:

```
    function validateForm(event){
    var form1 = document.getElementById("form1"),
    phone = document.getElementById("phonenumber").value,
    email = document.getElementById("email").value,
    name = document.getElementById("name").value,
    address = document.getElementById("address").value,
    tomatch = /^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/,
    emailMatch = /^\[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/;

    var errors = [];
    if (phone){
    event.preventDefault();
    errors.push("The Phone Number is required.");
    return false;
    } else if (tomatch.test(phone)){
        return true;
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        errors.push("The phone number must be formated as follows: XXX-XXX-XXXX.");
        return false;
    }

    if (name === null || name === " "){
        event.preventDefault();
        errors.push("The Name is required.");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

    if (email === null || email === " "){
        event.preventDefault();
        errors.push("The email is required.");
        return false;
    } else if (emailMatch.test(email)){
        return true;
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        errors.push("The email must be formated as follows: name@domain.com.");
        return false;
    }

    if (address === null || address === " "){
        event.preventDefault();
        errors.push("The Address is required.");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    if(errors.length > 0){
        for(var i=0;i<errors.length;i++){
            alert(errors)
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }   
}
```

html:

### Send Us An Email

```
                <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="assets/mailer.php" method="POST" id="form1" onSubmit="return validateForm()">
     <label for="Name">Name:</label><br />
     <input size="100%" type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
     <label for="Email">E-mail:</label><br />
     <input size="100%" type="text" name="email" id="email" value=""><br />
     <label for="Phone">Phone Number:</label><br />
     <input size="100%" type="text" name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber" value=""><br />
     <label for="Address">Shipping Address:</label><br />
     <input size="100%" type="text" name="address" id="address" value=""><br />

     <label for="comment">Input Comments/Questions:</label><br />
     <input size="100%" type="text" name="comment" value=""><br><br>
      Please choose a file: <br />
     <input name="uploaded" type="file" /><br />
     <br /> 

     <input size="100%" type="submit" value="Submit" /><br />
     <input size="100%" type="reset" value="Reset">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/validation.js">
```

Comment: it would be easier if you explained what you did rather than reading all that code and try to understand what's going on

Comment: Many javascript errors... Just check some documentation. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

Comment: The above link only shows validation for a single element, it does not take you through multiple elements. JavaScript is not my strength, so real help would be helpful as I can validate single elements without issue already, I am having trouble getting it to work on more than one Element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where to start from, but if you need your own validation you should remove `required` attribute from the inputs because FF for example will check the form instead of your validation function.

Executing event.preventDefault(); what do you think you have in `event`?

Properlly you should pass it when calling the function on submit and supply an argument in the function definition

```
onSubmit="validateForm(event);"
```

and function definition should be:

```
function validateForm(event) {
  ... 
  so you can do event.preventDefault()
  ...
}
```

You may have other problems too, but at least you will get the validation function executed and you;ll have event in it

COMPLETE EXAMPLE ADDED:

```
<script>

function validateForm(event) {

    var phone = document.getElementById("phonenumber").value,
    email = document.getElementById("email").value,
    name = document.getElementById("name").value,
    address = document.getElementById("address").value,
    tomatch = /^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/,
    emailMatch = /^\[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/,
    errors = [];

    if (!phone){
      errors.push("The Phone Number is required.");
    } else if (!tomatch.test(phone)){
      errors.push("The phone number must be formated as follows: XXX-XXX-XXXX.");
    }

    if (!name){
      errors.push("The Name is required");
    }

    if (!email){
      errors.push("The email is required.");
    } else if (!emailMatch.test(email)){
      errors.push("The email must be formated as follows: name@domain.com.");
    }

    if (!address){
      errors.push("The Address is required.");
    }

    if (errors.length) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert(errors.join("\n"));
    }

}
</script>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="assets/mailer.php" method="POST" id="form1" onSubmit="validateForm(event)">
 <label for="Name">Name:</label><br />
 <input size="100%" type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
 <label for="Email">E-mail:</label><br />
 <input size="100%" type="text" name="email" id="email" value=""><br />
 <label for="Phone">Phone Number:</label><br />
 <input size="100%" type="text" name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber" value=""><br />
 <label for="Address">Shipping Address:</label><br />
 <input size="100%" type="text" name="address" id="address" value=""><br />

 <label for="comment">Input Comments/Questions:</label><br />
 <input size="100%" type="text" name="comment" value=""><br><br>
  Please choose a file: <br />
 <input name="uploaded" type="file" /><br />
 <br />

 <input size="100%" type="submit" value="Submit" /><br />
 <input size="100%" type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Comment: The event is actually the mail sender, which after removing required from the form now does not get triggered as the JS stops it, but No errors are alerted. so I still can't see what is not working. Check the site link I just added.

Comment: As I told you have many errors ... but do what I've told about `event`... and change  `if (phone === null || phone === " ")`  with `if (phone)` so at least the phone will start validating. 1) do the event param passing I've mentioned 2) change your phone if ... 3) start debugging !!! if You use FireFox download FireBug addon (your best friend) ... put some preakpoints in the begining of your function ... many errors still to be corrected!

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` and  `return false` are doing the same thing, but `return false` soon will be deprecated.

Comment: No errors are found by firebug or Chrome but now it doesn't validate at all. Now I'm even more confused. I updated the code above to reflect the changes I have made.

Comment: Thank you so far, I found a huge issue that was my fault, no closing script tag, if you go to the site link above, it will not send unless you get the phone number right, but no alerts are issued to advise you what you have wrong?

Comment: I'll post a whole working page in my answer - check it

Comment: Thank you. I've been editing and testing piece by piece since I found the script tag error and was very close to the answer. Looks simple now. I am sorry I didn't get it myself, I'm new to JS, I prefer PHP.

Comment: No problem, but try next time to put small piece of code, for example validating of one field + simple JS with the problematic part. You will have fast answer. Otherwise there will be a few people which will look at you problem seriously and you won't get helped.  Cheers.